# PygLatin program in Python using String slicing

Tags: python

I have a Python code like this,

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word+first+pyg
    new_word[1:]
    print original
else:
    print 'empty'
```

The output of variable "new_word" should be "ythonpay", but now the new_word contains "pythonpay". Could anyone let me know what is the mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of the slice `new_word[1:]` to anything. You could just do the slice on your previous line, e.g.:

```
new_word = word[1:]+first+pyg
```

What version of python are you using, Python3 introduces a new unpacking syntax that makes this quite easy:

```
first, *word = original.lower()
new_word = word+first+pyg
```

No need to slice because the `*` assignment already separated the string.

Comment: I did not know about that `*`.  Do you happen to know of somewhere I can learn more about that?

Comment: Got it Sir, this solved the problem now i am getting 'ythonpay"

Comment: All changes to the python language are detailed in PEPs (Python Enhancement Proposals). The `unpacking operator` is covered [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). It is covered in the [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt) in the standard documentation but it just refers you to the above PEP. Argument unpacking has been in the language for a while, e.g. `func(*args)`.

Answer (score 0):

You say `new_word[1:]` but you aren't doing anything with it.  Change that to `new_word = new_word[1:]`.  [Slicing](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) creates a copy of the list with whatever items you decide.  In your case it creates a list of all items except the first.  It does not change the original list, however, so you need to assign `new_word` to it.

Comment: For example consider, I am giving python as my input which is the word here. So the variable first points to 'p' and my new_word should be set equal to the slice from the 1st index all the way to the end of new_word. So I am using [1:len(new_word)] to do this. So what might be my mistake here

Comment: `new_word[1:]` returns a list of all items except the first.  It does not change the original list.  That is why you need to redefine `new_word` so that *it* will be all of the items except the first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the indexing and what you are printing.

In your code `new_word = word+first+pyg` returns the original word itself as the first part, you need it to include all of the string except the first letter. That you can achieve by using `word[1:]` i.e all characters after the first (or 0th) index of the string.

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    # Here we take all the letters after the first letter.
    rest = word[1:]
    new_word = rest + first + pyg
    print new_word
else:
    print 'empty'
```

The above will output "ythonpay" for python.